# How to execute exe files on linux containers

Tags: .net, linux, docker, .net-core, wkhtmltopdf

In my .Net core web API, I'm using NuGet Package called [OpenHtmlToPdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenHtmlToPdf/)  for rendering HTML documents to PDF format. That OpenHtmlToPdf package internally uses [WkHtmlToPdf](https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf) native Windows library for HTML to PDF rendering. The application working fine with windows. But when I run the application in Docker on Linux containers, I'm getting following error.

**Permission denied**

```
{System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): Permission denied 
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec) 
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) 
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() 
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) 
   at OpenHtmlToPdf.HtmlToPdfConverterProcess.Convert(ConversionSource conversionSource) 
   at OpenHtmlToPdf.HtmlToPdfConverterProcess.ConvertToPdf(String html, IDictionary`2 globalSettings, IDictionary`2 objectSettings) 
   at OpenHtmlToPdf.Pdf.DocumentBuilder.ReadContentUsingTemporaryFile(String temporaryFilename) 
   at OpenHtmlToPdf.Pdf.DocumentBuilder.Content() 
   at core.notification.Messages.EmailMessage.GenerateEmailAttachmentPdf(String attchmentContent) in C:\Users\core.notification\Messages\EmailMessage.cs:line 165}
```

I check the container's files and there is an `.exe` file called `OpenHtmlToPdf.WkHtmlToPdf.exe`. OpenHtmlToPdf package using that when the PDF rendering process.

[image]

I think the above error arises, because, `.exe` files are Windows files; they won't run on Linux. How to handle this? please suggest me good approach to handle this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't execute Windows executables on Linux

Answer (score 1):

[OpenHtmlToPdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenHtmlToPdf/) only supports .NET Framework. No version of .NET Core or .NET 5 or 6 is listed. The last version is from 2014 which is an additional clue.

As .NET Framework does not run on Linux this package it is not going to work. (That you can compile only shows the code in the package that you compile against does not directly have the dependency issue.)

You need to find a different HTML to PDF converter (I know there are commercial ones, no idea about any free ones).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yeah I tried lots of free packages, but didn't work properly with my requirement. on this one worked fine. I found another free one https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenHtmlToPdf.netcore/ . it mentioned support for .Net core. But it also using WkHtmlToPdf.exe